# after adding .sh file to profile.d, desktop background does can not change, can't mount other partitions, and can't access trash

Tags: 13.04

So I was configuring my jdk and appending my PATH variable, and I put the script to do that in `profile.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash      
JAVA_HOME=[where I had the jdk installed]
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH JAVA_HOME
export CLASSPATH=.
```

I logged back in, and now I can't change my background from the default (It changed back), can't access the trash, and can't mount my window$ partition (to access those files).

Anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Files in profile.d are sourced, not executed. Therefore the shebang (#!/bin/bash) is not necessary. However that is not relevant to your problem. You can check that by moving that source file out of the way. You have to look for other things that have change, I am afraid.

Comment: That is literally the only change I made. I forgot to put EOF in the file when I put it in originally, is that going to change anything?

Comment: What do you mean by EOF? You mean literally `EOF`? That is just a made up magic string that stops a program like cat from waiting for another input from the TTY. If you mean the final EOL (end of line) in that file: that doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, if you suspect that file to screw up your system, then just move it away and check. That's the simplest thing you can do. But I'd say, it does no harm as it is. About what the strange `EOF` is about: [Here Document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: I did move it away and delete it. I don't know if I accidentally deleted one of the other .sh files in the directory. What files should be in there normally?

Comment: On my system there are bash-completion.sh and vte.sh from the packages bash-completion and libvte-common. But I actually use Linux Mint Cinnamon, i.e. I use Gnome not Unity. That's why you may not have the vte thing. You can do `dpkg -S /etc/profile.d/` in order to print packages that have assets in there and `dpkg -L <package> | grep /etc/profile.d` for which assets.

Comment: base-files, bash-completion, and libvte-2.90-common have dependencies in there, but the only .sh scripts are bash_completion.sh and vte.sh. Do I need any other scripts in there?

Comment: Nope. base-files owns the directory, but no files. You're safe. ;)

Comment: hmm, then why did this happen, and why can't I change it back?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell. It is not related to the original question, for sure.